# Eclipse JDT Compiler (ECJ) throws NPE in Java 1.7

Tags: java, compiler-construction, nullpointerexception, java-7, eclipse-jdt

I'm getting an NPE from the ECJ (version 4.2.1) compiler when running in JRE 1.7 the same project compiles properly on JRE 1.6.

A `CompilationProgress` monitor shows that there are Total of 2493 tasks, but then I get the NPE.

Any ideas?

TIA

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util.EclipseFileManager.concatFiles(EclipseFileManager.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util.EclipseFileManager.handleOption(EclipseFileManager.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchProcessingEnvImpl.(BatchProcessingEnvImpl.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchAnnotationProcessorManager.configure(BatchAnnotationProcessorManager.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.initializeAnnotationProcessorManager(Main.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.performCompilation(Main.java:3737)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1679)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1372)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch.BatchCompiler.compile(BatchCompiler.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch.BatchCompiler.compile(BatchCompiler.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of code that reproduces this?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg -- thank you for your reply.  the following command is causing this.  again, this is working properly in JRE6.  Compiler Command: -g -1.6 -extdirs "F:/Workspace/git/igal-getrailo/railo-java/libs;C:\Apps\railo-builder\webapps\railo-builder\WEB-INF\railo\lib\compile" -sourcepath F:/Workspace/git/igal-getrailo/railo-java/railo-loader/src[-d none] -d F:/Workspace/railo-build/railo-4.0.5.001-patch-d/__railo-core-bin F:/Workspace/railo-build/railo-4.0.5.001-patch-d/__railo-core-src

Comment: this is processed via reflection from a Railo (Servlet), the code that executes it is at: https://github.com/igal-getrailo/railo-builder/blob/1.1/resources/railo-builder/cfc/BuilderUtils.cfc#L14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be an Eclipse JDT bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405225

Hopefully it will be fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the exception is being caused inside of the command line args processing.  Specifically on the `-extdirs` option.  The `locations` object is null and the only way that this can be is if the `close()` method has already been called on the `EclipseFileManager`.  I can't see why exactly, but I would recommend that you grab the source code and fire this up in the debugger.

I know that this is not really an answer, but hopefully, this can at least get you a bit closer to solving the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help here, and will test in the debugger as you suggested.  any thoughts why this would work in JRE6 and not in JRE7?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that Java 6 and Java 7 handle extdirs and annotation processing differently, but this is only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm randomly guessing that you've run into a Windows problem I ran into with ECJ at one point, where the command line gets too long for Windows to handle.

What fixed it for me was putting the classpath alone in a text file and passing that to ECJ, but you should be able to add all your options to a text file and pass that instead, which would be safer long-term (see "Advanced options" @ http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm), something akin to:

- ecj-options.txt

  `-g -1.6 -extdirs "F:/Workspace/git/igal-getrailo/railo-java/libs;C:\Apps\railo-builder\webapps\ra‌​ilo-builder\WEB-INF\railo\lib\compile" -sourcepath F:/Workspace/git/igal-getrailo/railo-java/railo-loader/src[-d none] -d F:/Workspace/railo-build/railo-4.0.5.001-patch-d/__railo-core-bin`

Then adding @ecj-options.txt to the args, something like:

`java -jar ecj.jar @ecj-options.txt F:/Workspace/railo-build/railo-4.0.5.001-patch-d/__railo-core-src`

Comment: thanks Denny, but it appears that this is not the case.  I can see that all the args are passed properly.  the problem seems to be in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util.EclipseFileManager` at line 573 which (for ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_PATH) works in JRE6 but returns null in JRE7 -- see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.eclipse.jdt/com.springsource.org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/apt/util/EclipseFileManager.java#571

Comment: err: the value of location.getName() is "PLATFORM_CLASS_PATH" at that poin.  I've concluded that this is a bug and filed it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405225 -- thank you for your help.